# addEventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a problem with addEventListener. When I click on third div tag it doesn't change background color and alert is not working also.

Here is my html structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>
  <div>Robert</div>
  <div>Arthur</div>
  <div>Procedure(Third)</div>
  <div>Fourth</div>
  <button onclick="myfunc()">Try it</button>
</body>
```

Here is javascript file:

```
var Ar = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue"]

function getRandomInt(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function myfunc() {
    alert(getRandomInt(0,5));

}

function Group(handler) {
    var R = [];
    for (var I = 0, E = document.getElementsByTagName('div'), L = E.length; I < L; I++) {
        handler && handler.call(E[I]);
        if (!handler)
            R.push(E[I]);
     }
    return R;
 }

 //get third div tags and set a handler
 Group()[2].addEventListener("click", handler, false);

function handler() {
    alert("Test!"); 
    Group()[2].style.backgroundColor = Ar[getRandomInt(0,3)];   
 }
```

Comment: Start with `console.log` results of `Group()`

Comment: Your code [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/fo4kpmt0/) as expected?

Comment: @Teemu yes, but why on my PC in Chrome and Firefox it doesn't works? I can't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the elements before they get loaded.

Include your script at the end of the page and it will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>
  <div>Robert</div>
  <div>Arthur</div>
  <div>Procedure(Third)</div>
  <div>Fourth</div>
  <button onclick="myfunc()">Try it</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Robert Yes you can use onload, but the problem with that is that it will wait for all the resources like images to get loaded to emit onload event. A better option can be jquery's Document.ready.

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code like this.

```
<body>
    <p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>
    <div>Robert</div>
    <div>Arthur</div>
    <div>Procedure(Third)</div>
    <div>Fourth</div>
    <button onclick="myfunc()">Try it</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Group()[2].addEventListener("click", handler, false);
    </script>
</body>
```